# Compare files content and delete shorter ones

Tags: linux, file, cygwin

I have thousands of .txt files. I want to delete some of them. Some of the files are similar - the same content, but one is longer, and I need to remove the shorter one. All files lay down in one folder.

The only thing that is known about these files is that one file can have content

```
ABCDEFGH
```

and the other one

```
ABCDEF
```

but not

```
XYZ
```

What I need to do is to delete file `ABCDEF` which has a similar longer `ABCDEFGH` file. I expect n*(n-1) comparisons. Assume that files should be compared in binary form. Is there a script in bash (or generally Linux) that could do that for me? If I would have to do that, I would write a C# console app to compare all files and delete the similar but shorter ones, but I think it would be easier and faster in bash script (or on Linux). External tools are allowed. If the files have the same content and are the same length - one of files must remain in folder. There is possibility that there will be 3 or more files (with the same content) and (same length or different length).

Comment: How "similar" should file names be? i.e. Should  all of these files be also removed: `ABC` , `AB`, and `A` if a file with name `ABCDEFGH` exists?

Comment: You don't need n*(n-1) but only n*(n-1) /2 file comparisons - since if the file A and the file B where checked against each other, you don't need to recheck file B against file A ... (And it is possible to tell whether to compare file A against file B or file B against file A due to file size)

Comment: When you have two files with exactly the same file content. Do you want to remove both files, remove one file (which one based on filename, edit time, creation time, ...?) or keep both files?

Comment: It is not about filenames, but content of the files!! In case two files are the same content, one of them should not be deleted.

Comment: If you're looking for a solution with file content, then you'll need to include your work so far in your question. There are a few ways you could do this, but StackOverflow is about helping you fix your own code, we're not a free consultancy and coding service. Try to solve your own problem, and if/when you run into difficulty, that's the time to ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anybody interested in such Perl script will be happy. I assume that we have the script in current folder with *.txt files. If the file is the same as any other but longer or shorter, so there is some data in one of the files that makes it longer but not different for the front part, then the shorter file will be removed. For 1.3MB and 1300 files it took Cygwin Perl under 2 minutes to go through all files. Files are compared line by line. Script below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @files = <*.txt>;
my @del;
my $diff;
foreach my $file1 (@files) {
        foreach my $file2 (@files) {
                if ($file1 eq $file2) {
                        last;
                }
                open my $fh1, $file1 or die "can't open $file1: $!";
                open my $fh2, $file2 or die "can't open $file2: $!";
                print "Comparing $file1 and $file2...";
                my $line1;
                my $line2;
                $diff=0;
                while($line1 = <$fh1>) {
                        $line2 = <$fh2>;
                        if ($line1 ne $line2) {
                                print "different!\n";
                                $diff=1;
                                last;
                        }
                }
                if ($diff == 0) {
                        print "the same till end of one files!\n";
                        if (-s $file1 >= -s $file2)
                        {
                                push @del, $file2;
                        }
                        if (-s $file1 < -s $file2)
                        {
                                push @del, $file1;
                        }
                }
                close($fh1);
                close($fh2);
        }
}
foreach my $file (@del) {
        print "Removing $file\n";
        unlink $file;
}
```

Please be aware that encoding of the files and line endings may differ, so all the files, for example, should be UTF-8 encoded and line endings should be the same - LF.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following script (I did not include `rm` command, only `echo` for testing purposes):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Create some files for testing
touch ABCDEF                                                             
touch ABC
touch ACB
touch XABC  
touch XYZ                                                                                                                      
touch XY 

for fname1 in *; do                                                      
    for fname2 in *; do                                                  
        if [[ "$fname2" != "$fname1" && "$fname2" =~ "$fname1" ]]; then  
            echo -e "Short: $fname1 \tLong: $fname2"
        fi                                                               
    done                                                                 
done
```

This script will only search for files in the current directory. Output:

```
Short: ABC    Long: ABCDEF                                                  
Short: ABC    Long: ABCDEFGH 
Short: ABC    Long: XABC                                               
Short: ABCDEF Long: ABCDEFGH                                             
Short: XY     Long: XYZ
```

If you want to remove the "short" files then replace line of `echo` with

```
rm -i "$fname1" 2>/dev/null
```

I have not optimized this code, so it may be inefficient. Please let me know if this is the case and I will try to improve it.

Comment: It works for filenames, but the question is about content of the files (mentioned as "body"). Just edited the question.

Answer (score -1):

Your question doesn't specify whether you're talking about filenames or file content. I'll assume filenames, since that's possible as a one-liner.

The following might do:

```
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ for f in *; do for x in "$f"?*; do rm -v "$f"; continue 2; done; done
```

- This steps through your list of files (`*`), assigning each to `$f`.
- For each file, it uses one round of an inner for loop to determine
  whether a longer version of the filename exists.
- If a longer version
  exists, the shorter version is removed, and we continue with the
  outer loop.

The `nullglob` shell option saves us from having to test for the existence of the file `$x`.

Comment: Fixed the question, I'm sorry - I was thinking "body" is enough as name for "content".

Comment: Hm. A solution that compares the content of parts of files might be possible, but not with bash alone. You'll need external tools.